# Android TextToSpeach player didn't play sound

Tags: android

Hi i have a button from which i call the given methods the problem is when i click button for the first time TextToSpeach Player doesn't play the sound but handler code execute perfectly.If i click on button again everything work perfectly means TextToSpeach play the sound.Thank you..

```html
  public void selectDest() {
                TextToSpeechPlayer.playSound("hello");
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "After 1 sec  ");
                                }
                        },1000);
            }
```

Comment: Make sure that you enabled TexttoSpeech device settings.

Comment: I used TextToSpeach player many times in my application work perfectly but in this case for the first time doesn't work .i think something is wrong with handler.

Comment: Ok i got it, for the first time tts is not fully initialized that's why didn't play audio

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextToSpeechPlayer.playSound("hello");
      handler = new Handler();
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

    //do your other task here
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

Comment: didn't work. my aim is to first play the sound and after some time( 5 second ) some other code execute  but the problem is for the first time when click on button playing sound is skip.

Comment: i've modified the aswer. please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectDest() {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
            TextToSpeechPlayer.playSound("hello");
                            Log.d(TAG, "After 1 sec  ");
                            }
                    },1000);
        }
```